# Difference between CodedUI and UISpy

Tags: coded-ui-tests, ui-spy

What is the difference between CodedUI and UISpy? Does both use same mechanism? 
I need to implement support for UISPY in my own custom grid control[WinForms] to recognize each cell as like in the MS DataGridView. currently UISPY recognizes my entire control but not individual cell.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how UISpy works but CodedUI uses the UI Automation framework to access the UI components in an app.

Regardless, you might want to look at using something like [HawkEye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/) or [WinForms Spy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4814/A-simple-Windows-forms-properties-spy) as a starting point for doing what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have handled the AccessibleObject (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject.aspx) in my grid control and achieved the support to recognize each cell when spying through UISpy and UIVerify.

Comment: Coded UI can also use the older MSAA mechanisms (I believe they originated in Windows 95) for applications. Basically the application is coded to support UIA or MSAA or neither. It uses another interface for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The UI Spy tool is obsolete and no longer available. Developers should use other tools such as Inspect.exe that are available in the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK).